# Django - Sort the list into 3 columns on templates

Tags: python, django, algorithm, django-templates, django-views

My Models:

```
Item:
    name
    desc
    order
    created_at
```

And I got a list of items from **Item** like this:

```
items = Item.objects.all().order_by('order', '-created_at')
```

Now I send this list into templates. But I have to sort it in a pattern. For examples:

```
<ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>item 4</li>
    <li>item 5</li>
    <li>item 6</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>item 7</li>
</ul>
```

And with less items:

```
<ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 4</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>item 5</li>
</ul>
```

or shortening:

```
<ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>item 2</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Any idea? Thanks for help!

**UPDATE:** add reflections

```
<ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>item 3</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

or

```
<ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>item 4</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>item 5</li>
</ul>
```

or

```
<ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 4</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>item 5</li>
    <li>item 6</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>item 7</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check the [various snippets for partitioning lists](http://djangosnippets.org/search/?q=partition%20list)?

Answer (score 2):

I did this yesterday.

```
{% for link in footer_links %}
    {% if forloop.first or forloop.counter0|divisibleby:"6" %}
    <ul>
    {% endif %}
        <li><a href='{{ link.href }}'>{{ link.title }}</a></li>
    {% if forloop.last or forloop.counter|divisibleby:"6" %}
    </ul>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

it doesn't quite do three columns, but it splits the links up into lists of a certain length (6)

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly understand the criteria that is determining your grouping - is it literally just cycling through by 3?  If so, I think that the cycle template tag is what you are looking for:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#cycle

Comment: The right is always less than or equal to the left. I'm going to add some reflections.

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't understand the underlying desire - can you explain how the items are distributed?